# Error in running simple select inside sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using sql developer and just wanted to test one simple select query, with only one variable (P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID). But it is not possible to run this query:

```
declare P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID number := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM INV_SRV1 WHERE SRV_CATEGORY_ID IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM   inv_srv_category1
    START WITH parent_category_id = P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_category_id) OR SRV_CATEGORY_ID = P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID;
END;
```

The error (which I honestly don't understand) is:

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
declare P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID number := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM INV_SRV1 WHERE SRV_CATEGORY_ID IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM   inv_srv_category1
    START WITH parent_category_id = P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_category_id) OR SRV_CATEGORY_ID = P_SRV_CATEGORY_ID;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

As you were told: `INTO` clause is missing:

```
declare 
  p_srv_category_id number := 1;
  l_id              inv_srv1.id%type;       --> this
begin
  select id 
  into l_id                                 --> this
  from inv_srv1 
  where srv_category_id in (select id
                            from inv_srv_category1
                            start with parent_category_id = p_srv_category_id
                            connect by prior id = parent_category_id
                           ) 
     or srv_category_id = p_srv_category_id;
end;
```

---

Also, I'd suggest you to use table aliases. Without them, it is difficult to guess which column belongs to which table; Oracle gets confused as well sometimes and you get result you don't expect.

---

As of `too_many_rows` you got: I don't have your tables so I'll show you on Scott's EMP table: there are several employees in department 10:

```
SQL> select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER
```

This is what you are trying to do:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_empno emp.empno%type;
  3  begin
  4    select empno
  5      into l_empno
  6      from emp
  7      where deptno = 10;
  8  end;
  9  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

However, this works OK:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_arr sys.odcinumberlist;
  3  begin
  4    select empno
  5      bulk collect
  6      into l_arr
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = 10;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to actually *see* something, here's one option; note additional `FORALL`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_arr sys.odcinumberlist;
  3  begin
  4    select empno
  5      bulk collect
  6      into l_arr
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = 10;
  9
 10    forall i in 1 .. l_arr.count
 11      execute immediate 'call dbms_output.put_line(:1)' using l_arr(i);
 12  end;
 13  /
7782
7839
7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Now I have error ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: That's because query returns more than a single value. You'll have to restrict it, or - if you're storing more rows - change datatype to e.g. array or use ref cursor.

Comment: Please provide example. I've tried with refcursor, but I have another error PLS-00201: identifier 'REFCURSOR' must be declared. Basically your example would work only in the case if query returns just one row?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and your effor - id column is of type number. The error I am receiving now is: PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER

Comment: I presume you didn't `bulk collect into`, but just `into`.

Comment: That works, but I don't see any results. I was expecting to see results from that query. I've tried to add another select: SELECT * FROM l_arr but it throws another error.

Comment: if you want to see just the results - remove the begin/end and run just the SQL query itself. Otherwise, you are running  a PL/SQL script, that is a different thing. However, if you want to see the results of a query from the pl/sql block - you would need to go through the result set (cursor etc) and output each row separately

Comment: I added some more code which shows how to display those values. Have a look, please.